# cxf-java2ws-plugin and jaxb annotated classes

Tags: jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws, cxf

I'm trying to generate wsdl from java.

The plugin generates schema information for those classes included in the same project but seems not for classes in dependency packages.

```xml
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xxx" type="xs:anyType"/>
```

The `xxx` class is an JAXB annotated class and resides in different package with different (compile scoped) artifact.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. And I'm answering for my own question for further visitors.

Here comes two blog entries saved my days.

- http://city81.blogspot.kr/2011/11/jax-ws-jaxb-and-generics.html
- http://tunatore.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/how-to-use-xmlseealso-annotation-in-jax-ws/

Please, anybody, answer for me and others with some technical stuff.

My JAXB annotated classes look like this.

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance
abstract class Parent {
}

@Entity
class Sun extends Parent {
}

@Entity
class Daughter extends Parent {
}
```

All three classes seem work in JPA testing.

When it comes to JAX-WS, I need to annotate the `Parent` class with `@XmlSeeAlso`.

```java
@XmlSeeAlso({Sun.class, Daughter.class})
abstract class Parent {
}
```

Now I can work with

```java
abstract ParentService<P extends Parent> {
}

@WebService
class SunService extends ParentService<Sun> {
}
```